# Get event list based on location

Tags: facebook, api, events, location

I've been digging around on the Facebook developer site to see if there is a way to get local event information for display on my own web app.

Ideally, I would pass up a location and Facebook would send down a list of local public events (with links to FB of course).
But as yet I haven't found any documentation which says whether this is possible.

Does anyone know if this is possible?

Answer (score 2):

It is possible indeed to receive events using location based "search"
To do so you'll need the longitude and latitude coordinates of the location you want to search and a access_token with user_events permission (i think you could also use the public search)

Here's an FQL example how can you get all the events nearby of a location. (this searches from your and your friends events):

```
$lat = "40";
$long = "30";

// using offset gives us a "square" on the map from where to search the events
$offset = 0.4;

$events = 'SELECT pic_big, name, venue, location, start_time, eid FROM event WHERE eid IN (SELECT eid FROM event_member WHERE uid IN (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me()) AND start_time > '. $created_time .' OR uid = me()) AND start_time > '. $created_time .' AND venue.longitude < \''. ($long+$offset) .'\' AND venue.latitude < \''. ($lat+$offset) .'\' AND venue.longitude > \''. ($long-$offset) .'\' AND venue.latitude > \''. ($lat-$offset) .'\' ORDER BY start_time ASC '. $limit;
```

The trick itself lies in the venue.longitude and venue.latitude useage. To get events from a city, just get the city coordinates and adjust the offset to your needs.
If you don't know how to use FQL please look into [Facebook PHP SDK](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/php/)

Comment: As this answer is about 10 months old, I cannot guarantee that Facebook hasn't changed their API.

If I have some time, I'll look into it again and post new answer.

Comment: Is not possible to do it like that since FQL is deprecated after the Facebook API version 2.1

Comment: Correction: You can still use FQL until August 7th 2016 [docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog)

Answer (score 0):

the quotes around the lat/longitude makes them a string. You'd be then comparing a float to a string